# MinIO poor performance on PUT requests

Tags: minio, synology, diagnostics, k3s

I am running 4 instances of MinIO in a k3s cluster, the servers operating MinIO have low processor usage and low ram usage they seem to be purring along like a fat kid eating cake.

All except one, this specific instance is struggling with put requests, time varies from 0.5 seconds to 17.5 seconds.

I have run several diagnostics including the deprecated

```
mc admin heal -r myminio
```

This returned some worrying stats, including
0.2% in red
0.1% in yellow
All the other sites are 100% green.

So this points at disk being the issue but I dont believe this is conclusive. Since this should repair and certainly does not warrant 17 seconds put request time.

Finally the question:

What diagnostics can be run on these instances and is there some form of documentation around this. I have been all over the web, also tried posting in MinIO slack channel without luck.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

persistent volumes are attached using `nfs-subdir-external-provisioner`

The underlying physical storage uses `Synology Drive`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tracing, debugging and slamming my head on the desk for a while...

NFS share permissions were setup in such a way that asynchronous writes were disabled.

Nothing to do with MinIO nothing to do with Synology.

Incorrect setup.